# How to use the legend names as ticks of the x axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I tried to plot **Chondrit REE** values like you can find in geochemistry literature.

Processed example data:

```
listech=([0.94  0.47    0.48    0.41    2.55    6.83    8.09    59.70   16.64   38.25   11.20   38.27   9.79    34.036  38.50])
listechStrings=([La Ce  Pr  Nd  Sm  Eu  Gd  Tb  Dy  Ho  Er  Tm  Yb  Lu  YY])
```

Just a semilogy plot of the mean concentration values from listech with the names of the Elements from listech Strings at the x axis. I need a program to help me to analyze hundreds of listech's files.

```
I tried:
fn = '%s/Chondrite_REE.png' % (fnFigFolderSub)
for ii,l in enumerate(listech):
  plt.semilogy(time, l, label=listechStrings[ii])
title('Chondrite_REE')
grid(True)
legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
savefig(fn)
close()
```

It plot concentration at the x-axis and time at the y-axis, plus a lengend box. It is just a part of the code. If you do not need time you can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
y = np.array([0.94,0.47,0.48,0.41,2.55,6.83,8.09,59.70,16.64,38.25,11.20,38.27,9.79,34.036,38.50])
my_xticks = ['La', 'Ce',  'Pr',  'Nd',  'Sm',  'Eu',  'Gd',  'Tb',  'Dy', 'Ho',  'Er', 'Tm',  'Yb',  'Lu',  'YY']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.semilogy(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.save()
```

Thanks to Stackover community

Comment: Which library are you using for plotting? What have you tried?

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: fn = '%s/Chondrite_REE.png' % (fnFigFolderSub)
for ii,l in enumerate(listech):
  plt.semilogy(time, l, label=listechStrings[ii])
title('Chondrite_REE')
grid(True)
legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
savefig(fn)
close()

Comment: Hello Vivek. This is part of the primary code. It prints concentration over time with the Element as labels. I do not need the time. Just a log plot of concentration with the Elements as ticks of the x-axis.

Comment: @SheelaS.  You can edit your question to add the information from your comments.

Comment: Dear Vivek Kumar Found

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
y = np.array([0.94,0.47,0.48,0.41,2.55,6.83,8.09,59.70,16.64,38.25,11.20,38.27,9.79,34.036,38.50])
my_xticks = ['La', 'Ce',  'Pr',  'Nd',  'Sm',  'Eu',  'Gd',  'Tb',  'Dy', 'Ho',  'Er', 'Tm',  'Yb',  'Lu',  'YY']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.semilogy(x, y)
plt.show()